# dd/ddrescue style tool for SSDs that skips writes for identical blocks

Tags: ssd, restore, dd, ddrescue

I have a dd copy of a filesystem from a SSD I want to restore back to the same SSD filesystem due to a bad OS crash, putting it back into a known good state.  95% of the blocks will be the same, so to avoid wear on the SSD I don't want to have ddrescue write blocks to the SSD that are identical to the blocks in the dd copy.

Is there a tool equivalent to dd or ddrescue or command line flags to the tools that will not write identical blocks on the destination?  It'll be slower since it'll do a read and optionally write, but I'm ok with the slowdown.

Comment: There's no way with standard tools to know what bits are written to which storage location. The controller abstracts this away. Go with Mechanical snail's suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

It should be possible to do this using [`rsync`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync), the differential data transfer tool.

See [the man page](http://rsync.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html), and use the `--inplace` option because you want to write directly into the device file.

That said, a single write pass across the disk is a trivial amount of wear, so consider just `dd`ing it over.

Comment: Thanks, I use rsync all the time, but wasn't aware that --inplace works with device files.

Comment: It's not working with rsync 3.0.9 on RHEL5:bash-3.2#

    $ rsync -P --inplace md0.image /dev/md0 
    md0.image
     18883313664   2%  118.28MB/s    1:26:10
    rsync: writefd_unbuffered failed to write 4 bytes to socket [sender]: Broken pipe (32)
    rsync: write failed on "/dev/md0": No space left on device (28)
    rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at receiver.c(322)     [receiver=3.0.9]
    rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (28 bytes received so far) [sender]
    rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(605) [sender=3.0.9]

Comment: Turns out that even with --inplace, rsync 3.0.9 clobbers /dev/md0 first.

Comment: Is it trying to append?

Answer (score 0):

`e2image` from e2fstools can do this with the `-c` option, but it can't read an input image from stdin as it seems to need to seek around.

The "old" `dd_rescue` tool (which is not the same as GNU ddrescue) has a `-W` option to avoid writes and *can* read from stdin: https://sourceforge.net/projects/ddrescue/ You might want `-a` as well to skip writing blocks of zeros, depending on the situation (I'm currently looking at restoring images to LVM thin pools while preserving the CoW characteristics.)